# MySql insert statement to binary datatype?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL database.

I have one table having column with datatype binary(16).

I need help with the insert statement for this table.

```
Example:
CREATE TABLE `assignedresource` (
`distid` binary(16) NOT NULL
)

insert into assignedresource values ('9fad5e9e-efdf-b449');

Error : Lookup Error - MySQL Database Error: Data too long for column 'distid' at row 1
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: You're trying to insert 18 bytes to a 16-byte field. What did you expect? How to fix - insert less bytes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should remove the hyphens to make the value match the length of the field...

```
Example:
CREATE TABLE `assignedresource` (
`distid` binary(16) NOT NULL
)

insert into assignedresource values ('9fad5e9eefdfb449');
```

Also, MySQL standard is to use this notation to denote the string as binary... X'9fad5e9eefdfb449', i.e.

```
insert into assignedresource values (X'9fad5e9eefdfb449');
```

Comment: Thought I should note that every two characters represents a binary byte. So I believe the string in question (after the dashes are removed) is a binary(8).

Answer (score 4):

Well, assuming that you want to strictly **insert a hexadecimal string**, first you need to **remove the dashes and then "unhex"** your string before inserting it into a binary(16) data type column, the code would go like this:

```
INSERT INTO `assignedresource` VALUES(UNHEX(REPLACE('9fad5e9e-efdf-b449','-','')));
```

Also... the **"usable"** data you are inserting is actually **8 bytes** after **undashing** it, so **binary(8)** would do fine if you plan on not storing the dashes.

Answer (score 2):

You can strip the hyphens and perpend 0x to the value unquoted, like this:

```
insert into assignedresource values (0x9fad5e9eefdfb449);
```

As well as, as this (mentioned in other answers):

```
insert into assignedresource values (X'9fad5e9eefdfb449');
```

Both are valid notation for a [hexadecimal literal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/hexadecimal-literals.html).

Answer (score -1):

Your string is 18 char long, change the database

```
CREATE TABLE `assignedresource` (
`distid` binary(18) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Aren't strings in mysql null terminated (19 bytes required)?

Comment: AFAIK, MySQL doesn't care about null termination. So it's a matter of conversion at client side. But nothing prevents one from storing all 19 bytes and point to raw data on the client side.